# how to call an angular method in html?

Tags: angular

I have an angular function that returns an integer .All i want that is to call this function in html. How can I do that?

I tried two way data binding in html like `{{functionname()}}` to call function but that didn't work.Here is my function:

```
getTodaysOrder(){
  return this.http.get(this.url+'/GetTodaysOrder').subscribe(data => { 
    this.formData = data as number;  
  });
}
```

Comment: How you want to trigger the function ? From button click ? or initial page load ?

Comment: You don't want to call function in your template, *especially* a function that makes a http-call. This will kill your browser because of it being called over and over. Instead call the function on for example `OnInit` if that is what you want, and show `{{formData}}` in the template instead.

Comment: i want to trigger this in initial page load

Comment: Thanks rahul and AJT_82 for feedback. It works

Answer (score 2):

Add function in OnInit if you want to call function on page load

```
OnInit(){
  this.getTodaysOrder();
  }

getTodaysOrder(){
  return this.http.get(this.url+'/GetTodaysOrder').subscribe(data => { 
    this.formData = data as number; 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
As "[Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5591211/rich)" correctly pointed out, the direct call of a method in HTML will execute it quite often.
This behavior is because of the digestive cycle. When a value that is bound to the DOM changes, the digestive cycle will kick in ( at least as long as the change detection is active). The digestive cycle will run through all bound variables (and methods) and check their value. After that it will do that again. It will do that until two successive runs create no changes in any variable (or until the maximum amout of runs, 10 i think).
Because of that it is a bad practice to call long running methods (like backend calls) from HTML. There it is better to trigger the method once (e.g. ngOnInig, or on specific activity of the user) and store the result in a variable. And use that variable in HTML.
**@Rich**, thanks to point that out, i really forgot to mention that.
END OF EDIT:

at first, your function needs to be known in your component.
If your function is one of the methods of your component than thats an easy go, it just have to be public (if you do not provide an access modifier, than it is public by default)

```
class MyComponent {
  public myFunction(): number {
    return 1234;
  }
}
```

If your function is declared elsewhere, then you first have to make it known in your component.

```
function myExternalFunction(): number {
    return 1234;
}

class MyComponent {
  public myFunction(): ()=>number = myExternalFunction;
  }
}
```

in both cases then you can access that method directly by calling it in HTML

```
<span> {{ myFunction() }} </span>
```

or if you want to provide it to another component or an html attribute as in input, then you have (like with variables) to use the [...]="..." notation.

I hope that helps

warm regards
Jan

Comment: You really should try to avoid putting a function call as the value to display in interpolation. Angular's change detection lifecycle causes the function to be called repeatedly. You can test it by putting a console.log in the function call. Instead it is better to insure that the function is called once (such as during ngOnInit), and store the resultant value in a class member variable, which the template shows.

Comment: For example, I added `{{test()}}` and `test(){console.log("test"); return 123;}` to a simple page. You see "test" in the console several dozen times, just in the 1-2 secs it takes to load the page. Doing other things on the page calls the function again, and you see more "test"s showing in the console. Now imagine doing this if you had http calls or complex operations to get the display value. It gets very inefficient, very fast.

Comment: @Rich - Thanks for reminding me. I really forgot to mention that. I updated my answer.